# The best way to play swf-files (flash) in my android-program?

Tags: java, android, flash

I have to play flash (swf) in my program when the user clicks on a link. Which is best? Concentrate on android 2.2 and use the Adobe Flash Player, or what do you recommend? I have tested WebView, but can not play swf in the emulator. HTC has a custom flash player but it feel like a limitation.

Some code samples to play swf in android that works for as many users as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Flash to create an AIR app for Android rather than using Java?  If you have to download and run external swf files, this seems like a path of least resistance to me.  Of course, this requires learning ActionScript, but it's not difficult if you know Java.

Comment: Wouldn't this require to have adobe air installed on the phone?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka You can use captive runtime in order to package AIR into your app.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to give you a solid recommendation, much like toggy-tog-togs answer. B/c we don't know exactly how many swfs or what kind of swfs you are playing.

I mean, if your application is pretty much just playing swf's and you need a UI to run it, it might be worth looking at Air and Flex.

However, to address that first problem you had. I haven't tested it myself, but I am nearly 100% certain, that your emulator won't play flash content in a webview b/c you don't have flash player installed on the emulators. :-) Android supports Flash content but only after you download and install the player from the App store.

So you might want to try running your emulator and installing the Flash player app.  I don't even know if that is possible but you ought to try it out. :-)

By the way, the Android emulator is trash, if you are serious about developing for the Android platform, you really have to pick up a device or two to debug on.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

So your using JAVA if you are then it is best to open up the browser that is the easiest but if you are wanting to use it in the application (This is less loading time if it is included in the package) but it costs try using JFlashPlayer (It Costs For the full version) http://www.jpackages.com/jflashplayer/download/ This runs very fast on the android platform. Hope I could help.